# New Intune profile deployment best practices

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, intune

I'm trying to find information about best practices in rolling out changes using profiles to Win10 devices managed in Intune. In AirWatch world, I usually create a new profile which includes the latest set of configuration and gradually phase it out to a predefined set of user- groups slowly increasing adoption numbers (PCT-PILOT-REGION-ESTATE WIDE) with soak time in between. I would like to do something similar in Intune. What approach should I take?

Comment: Which guide are you using currently? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/device-profile-create

Comment: I have a clear understanding of how to create profiles this is not an issue. I want to learn about release management strategy. How do you phase a release, what are the best practices?